# Need help with `expand-region`: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-outline-overlay-data

Tags: org-mode, debugging

If I try to use `er/expand-region` but it fails with `Symbol’s function definition is void: org-outline-overlay-data`.

`org-version` :
Org mode version 9.2.2

In the release notes for the current org (9.2), it says that `org-outline-overlay-data` has been removed.

But there is no `org-outline-overlay-data` in the `expand-region` code when I search the package directory.

```
#### System Info
- OS: gnu/linux
- Emacs: 26.1
- Spacemacs: 0.300.0
- Spacemacs branch: develop (rev. fba6d38bf)
- Graphic display: t
- Distribution: spacemacs
```

Comment: Something loaded by your init file is clearly trying to invoke that missing function. Bisect your init file to find the culprit. If the problem comes from some code your init file loads then that will tell which code file that is. If necessary you can then bisect that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just delete `~/.emacs.d/elpa/*/develop/expand-region*` and spacemacs will re-install it.

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/12099#issuecomment-480904298

> @flatwhatson
> The problem is that expand-region is byte-compiled with the built-in org, but then the org layer installs a newer version from ELPA which has changed the definition of the org-save-outline-visibility macro, leading to the symbol error.

---

As an alternative, you can try to update/reinstall the `expand-region` package via `M-x package-reinstall RET expand-region RET` (you might have to do `M-x package-refresh-contents RET` first to update your package index from ELPA.)

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Comment: I'm not using spacemacs but I deleted `expand-region` from `.emacs.d/el-get` and reinstall it and that solved the problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using spacemacs, but the problem is still the same.

I'm using [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) and [straight.el](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) to manage my packages.

The same problem as noted by BlindingDark in the quote by flatwhatson is the problem.

`expand-region` is using the built-in `org` and not the newer one loaded by use-package.

This is easily fixed by telling use-package to load after `org` has been loaded.

```
(use-package expand-region
  :after (org)
```

Comment: I am using too use-package and straight, but this :
(use-package expand-region :after (org)) doesnt work for me :(
Do you have a other option ?

Comment: @Cletip No sorry, as this worked for me I haven't looked into trying alternatives. Best I can suggest is trimming your .emacs down to bare bones and fiddle with load order.